# illegal base64 data error message

Tags: go

I'm building an API that accepts JSON data POSTed to it.

I have the following `user` struct and recently I changed the `password` datatype to `[]byte` from `string` so that it "plays nicely" with the bcrypt package.

```
type User struct {
    Id           string             `json:"id,omitempty"`
    Email        string             `json:"email,omitempty"`
    Username     string             `json:"username,omitempty"`
    Password     []byte             `json:"password,omitempty"`
    Name         string             `json:"name,omitempty"`
}
```

However, I'm now getting an internal error returned in the JSON response **illegal base64 data at input byte 4** when a user is POSTed with a password of 5 or more characters to the API. There are no issues if the password is 4 or less characters.

I've pinpointed the error to this block of code:

```
err := json.NewDecoder(req.Body).Decode(User)
if err != nil && err != io.EOF {
    return err
}
```

Any ideas on a fix?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The problem lies in using `[]byte` instead of `string` for password. This is because the `encoding/json` package will expect a base64 encoded string when decoding to `[]byte`.

The documentation for [`encoding/json`](http://golang.org/pkg/encoding/json/#Marshal) says:

> Array and slice values encode as JSON arrays, except that []byte encodes as a base64-encoded string, and a nil slice encodes as the null JSON object.

So, just change it to `string`:

```
Password string `json:"password,omitempty"`
```

When you want to use it with bcrypt, then you just convert the `string` to `[]byte`:

```
[]byte(user.Password)
```

Comment: Thanks but as I mentioned in my question I changed from string to byte so that it works with the bcrypt package. Would you just recommend typecasting the string value to byte for bcrypt and then back to string for saving?

Comment: @tommyd456 Welcome :) . At first I missed the reason why you were using []byte, focusing just on the error. Sorry for that!

Comment: So generally it's better to just use `string` for json field?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to extract a byte array directly from JSON, you can use the datatype `*json.RawMessage`, which is defined at `encoding/json/stream.go:247` (in Go 1.9) as:

```
type RawMessage []byte
```

This special type instructs the unmarshaller to skip decoding and simply create a slice of the relevant bytes.  Since this is still just a byte array though, you can use it directly with bcrypt functions:

```
type User struct {
    ...
    Password     *json.RawMessage   `json:"password,omitempty"`
    ...
}

...

err := bcrypt.CompareHashAndPassword(*user.Password, storedPassword)
```

Note the pointer dereference (`*`) when reading the value.